# Laravel Insert Data to Pivot Table From blade.php

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I wanted to know what modifications should I do to this form to be able to link the newly added question to a group for example question that I am adding now says what's your name? I want it to be linked to group one so that only users in group 1 can see it

this is my Question Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Question extends Model
{
    public function answer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer')->latest();
    }

    public function userAnswer(){
      return $this->hasOne('App\Answer')->where('user_id', Auth()->id())->latest()->first();
    }
    public function group()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class);
    }

}
```

This is my Group Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Group extends Model
{
  public function question()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Question');
  }
}
```

This is my Group_Question Table ( Pivot table containing question_id and group_id )

```
 Schema::create('group_question', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('group_id');
        $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('question_id');
        $table->foreign('question_id')->references('id')->on('questions')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
      });
```

and finally this is the form that I use to add Questions to the questions table:

```
<form class="" action="/questions/create" method="post">
          @csrf

          <div  class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="question" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Enter Question">
          </div>

          @can('add', \App\Question::class)
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-success float-right">Add Question</button>
          </div>
          @endcan

        </form>
```

I would really appreciate it if you can edit my from to be able to assign the question to a group in the pivot table.

Comment: I think you need a dropdown for the group list in add question form

Comment: how can I make th3 @can(add for  2 models? Question and Group)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a multi select in order to be able to assign groups to a Question. Since $question->group is a belongsToMany relation, you can obvisouly assign a question to multiple groups. You can do something like this:

```
<select name="groups[]" multiple="multiple">
    @foreach ($groups as $group)
        <option value="{{ $group->getKey() }}">{{ $group->name }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Caveat:

1. `$groups` should be exported by the `create` action of your QuestionController and be something like `$groups = Group::get()`. Alternatively you could write `@foreach (Group::get() as $group)` in your blade template, but keeping as much logic out of your template as possible is a good habit to get into.
2. `$group->name` is just a guess, not knowing how your group table looks like
3. The example HTML is just the bare minimum to get you started, you should make sure that on validation error etc. the old values are prefilled. I leave that to you as an excercise.

Next, go to your QuestionController and link the question to the appropriate groups by adding the following line to your `store` method:

```
$question->group()->attach($request->input('groups', [])));
```

---

Bonus remarks:

1. To follow Laravel best practices, the group relation in the Question model should be studly case and plural, as it is a `BelongsToMany` relation. Thus, you should rename it to `Groups()`.
2. The answer() method should also be called `Answers()`.
3. It is a little weird that you define a new `HasOne` relationship within the `userAnswer()` getter. Why not implement a getter or custom attribute for the current user's Answer instance instead by doing something like

   ```
   public function getUserAnswerAttribute(): ?App\Answer
   {
       return $this->Answer()->whereUserId(Auth()->id())->first();
   }
   ```

(if you are not familiar with attributes: you can then just call `$question->userAnswer` to get the result).

4. Can each user really only post one Answer to each Question?
5. You might want to use `<form action="{{ route('question.create') }}" method="POST">` instead of hardcoding the URL. That's what named routes are there for.